# de Broglie vs Schrodinger models: Why is the IR spectra different in PhET simulation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, simulations

I was playing around with the PhET simulation "Models of the Hydrogen Atom", https://phet.colorado.edu/en/simulation/legacy/hydrogen-atom . In it you can simulate a hydrogen atom's electron absorbing and emitting photons, based on different atomic models. You can also plot the photons emitted/nm on a simulated spectrometer.

I set the simulation to white light, running at maximum speed.

After leaving it running for a while, the spectrum for the de Broglie model forms about six distinct peaks in the IR range. If I do the same for the Schrodinger model then only 3 distinct peaks form in the IR range. Why is there a difference?

The Schrodinger model differentiates between values for the orbital quantum number, whereas the de Broglie model does not. I'm aware that there is a selection criterion that the orbital quantum number must change by +/- 1 when transitioning between energy levels, so that will cause certain transitions to become less likely. But transitions between the energy levels 6->3, 4->3, and 5->4 never seem to happen with the Schrodinger model, even though these transitions can abide by the selection criteria. What makes these transitions less likely/not allowed, and why do they appear much more frequently in the de Broglie model?

I'd ask that answers are kept relatively simple, I'm currently only in my first year at university.